# [Errno 2]: No such file or directory error even though file exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Here's the code

```
WORKSPACE_PATH='C:/Users/p/OneDrive/Desktop/ObjectDetection/RealTimeObjectDetection/Tensorflow/workspace'
SCRIPTS_PATH= 'C:/Users/p/OneDrive/Desktop/ObjectDetection/RealTimeObjectDetection/Tensorflow/scripts'
APIMODEL_PATH='C:/Users/p/OneDrive/Desktop/ObjectDetection/RealTimeObjectDetection/Tensorflow/models'
ANNOTATION_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH+'/annotations'
IMAGE_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH+'/images'
MODEL_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH+'/models'
PRETRAINED_MODEL_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH+'/pre-trained-models'
CONFIG_PATH = MODEL_PATH+'/my_ssd_mobnet/pipeline.config'
CHECKPOINT_PATH = MODEL_PATH+'/my_ssd_mobnet/'

labels = [{'name':'Nut', 'id':1}, {'name':'Bolt', 'id':2}]

with open(ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt', 'w') as f:
    for label in labels:
        f.write('item { \n')
        f.write('\tname:\'{}\'\n'.format(label['name']))
        f.write('\tid:{}\n'.format(label['id']))
        f.write('}\n')

!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x {IMAGE_PATH + '/train'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/train.record'}
!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x{IMAGE_PATH + '/test'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/test.record'}
```

And the error message I get is

```
python: can't open file 'C:/Users/p/OneDrive/Desktop/Object': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'C:/Users/p/OneDrive/Desktop/Object': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Have tried looking this up for several hours now but can't seem to figure out what's wrong. I've copied this code and it seems to be working just fine for everyone else.

Comment: It seems that it is trying to open `Object` which does not exist. does it say on which line the error occurs? is that the whole error?

Comment: also try just typing the whole path in there manually (one whole string) and see if it works then

Comment: The error is about `Object` path and not `ObjectDetection`.

Comment: Nope! Doesn't work. And the error is after the last two lines of code!

Comment: Looks like your script is not reading complete path, change the `ObjectDetection` folder name and try. It might have space or special character. Thanks!